# Laravel Throws ReflectionException Since Update to Version 5.1.7

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

I'd been working on my portfolio development with a blog alongside on `Laravel 5.1.2` lately. It all was working fine till the moment I needed the `illuminate/html` package. Also, prior to running the `composer require illuminate/html` command, I ran the `composer update` command to let all the libraries update to their newer versions.

But that's where the problem crept in. Since, the upgrade to `Laravel 5.1.7` and the installation of the `illuminate/html` package, the project has gone haywire and has been throwing barking mad

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 736:
Class view does not exist
```

And I haven't the slightest clue where this is arising from.

**PS**: I have also updated the `app.php` file to include the respective `providers` and `aliases` corresponding to `illuminate/html`.

**Update**
Here's the code from my controller files if it might be of any help.
*PagesController.php (I generated it as a plain stub via the --plain artisan option)*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('pages.home');
    }
}
```

*ArticleController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('blog.index', compact('articles'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('blog.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        return view('blog.show', compact('article'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Windows or Linux? Could be a problem with case sensitivity. I.e. `View` instead of `view`. Maybe?

Comment: I'm running it on a Windows machine. Also, I'm not sure which `view` class it might be referring to. One thing's for sure though, that it is case-sensitive.

Comment: have you add use view in your controller file?

Comment: The only places I've used `view`s in my controller files is where I have returned the control to the view, as in, `return view('folder.view', compact('variable'));`

Comment: I created a new application and replicated all the files in the above application into the new one. And it worked like magic. Now the only thing I wish to figure is where did this go wrong.